# Can we access user session variable in tomcat admin manager application?

Tags: java, tomcat, server, ip

If user set his IP address in a session, then can tomcat admin(http://localhost:8080/manager/) access the session variable?

Comment: No you can't. Session is restricted to particular app, another application cannot access it. Why do you want to try this?

Comment: Its for tracking the ip addresses of active sessions for a web application. If you have any idea about this , please share, Thanks